# JAVAFX Derby Client Server, do I need two different builds?

Tags: javafx, derby

I am building application in javafx using Derby embedded DB. Do I need to create two separate builds in order to run it as client server ?

Answer (score 0):

The primary differences are:

1. different syntax for the JDBC Connection URL, and
2. different Derby jars in the CLASSPATH.

It is possible to include both sets of Derby jars in the CLASSPATH, meaning that the only thing your application must vary at runtime in the JDBC Connection URL.

derbyclient.jar is significantly smaller than derby.jar, however, so if executable package size is crucial to you, you might find it worth the effort to have two different modes of packaging.

Comment: Right, so how I will differentiate between Client and Server ?

Comment: How will **you** differentiate? I'm sorry, I don't understand that question. To deploy in client-server mode, you (a) start the server, (b) configure your app to run in client mode, (c) start your app. Is that what you mean?

Comment: for example i have 2 machines. one is server and one is client. same build is installed on both. both machine should share db from one source which is server. how server machine build will know it is server ? or how client machine will know it is client ?

Comment: You have a **LOT** of choices here. For example, you could have both your machines be clients, and run the Derby server on a third machine. Or, you could have both your machines be clients, and pick one of those machines and **also** run the Derby server on that machine. Many more variations are possible. A lot depends on your underlying needs. But I'd start by having both machines run the client version of your app, and install the Derby network server on one of your two machines.

Comment: Sorry to bother you once more. I am trying to understand the scenario here. If I have same build on both the machines, how the same build will run the server and other not ? Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: The Derby server is not a piece of software you write. It comes with Derby, as part of the distribution. See: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/adminguide/cadminov825266.html

Comment: by build I meant my application.